# which statistical test can be useful without replicate

Tags: r, statistical-significance, permutation-test

am wondering if one knows which method is a correct way to go with such a data I have 4 conditions where I obtained the microarray data. I don't have a control and all 4 conditions are treated ones. I want to know which genes are changed in each condition in comparison to the rest.

So imagine I have a matrix of 4 by 18000 (4 samples and 18000 genes).

I just put a R data example here

```
df <- structure(list(Names = structure(c(2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 8L, 7L, 
11L, 9L, 10L), .Label = c("", "AA", "AB", "AC", "AD", "AF", "JA", 
"JJ", "KA", "LF", "NM"), class = "factor"), X1 = c(0.006605138, 
0.001165448, 0.006975109, 0.002207839, 0.00187902, 0.002208638, 
0.001199808, 0.001162252, 0.001338847, 0.001106317), X2 = c(0.006041392, 
0.001639298, 0.006140877, 0.002958169, 0.002744017, 0.003107995, 
0.001729594, 0.001582564, 0.001971713, 0.001693236), X3 = c(0.024180351, 
0.002189061, 0.027377442, 0.002886651, 0.002816333, 0.003527908, 
0.00231891, 0.001695633, 0.00212034, 0.001962923)), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: This doesn't sound like a statistical question.  It sounds like a comparison question.

Comment: @StatsStudent this might be , however, I want to know which approah would be best to follow which I could not find. some says just a simple t test some says permutation etc

Comment: You stated that your goal is to know which genes are changed in each condition.  If that's your goal, can't you just scan each gene and compare or is that somehow impossible to do for some reason (this isn't my area of expertise).  A t-test looks to determine if there are average differences (it's a summary measure) as opposed to an individual-level difference test.

Comment: @StatsStudent I just put a R example data

Comment: 4 samples and 18000 genes? Forget it. You need more data.